# my new mechanical timers need 4 wires ; how do I put a 4 wire into my so far only 3 wires into service box. 120 v. all along

Tags: electrical

My new mechanical timers need 4 wires (ground/white/red/black);
How do I put a 4 wire into my so far only 3 wires only (white/black/ground)
into service box ? So far only 3 wires used for all 120v breakers Timer & appliance
use 120 volt only.

Comment: Should have a wiring diagram/instructions with the timers.  If not, then a possibility these timers are not safe to use.

Comment: Make and Model #?

Comment: one wire is the output signal

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.